# Critique - Logo for company that cleans medical linens

Tags: logo, critique, designers

A company known as MedLinens has asked me to create a logo for them. They specialize in cleaning medical linens i.e scrubs, gowns, bed sheets. I have shown the client a few logos but the attached one had the most positive response. However, they critiqued that the logo was too round for their liking. Any ideas how I could "square" up this logo without losing the main innuendos of the logo (heart, stethoscope, collar)? I was also thinking of just scrapping this whole idea and creating new a new square-like logo and any ideas would be greatly appreciated. 
[image: MedLinenLogo]

Answer (score 4):

It's attractive, but it looks dated. The stethoscope concept is really coming through, even though the lower portion is missing, so good job there. 
Scrubs have no lapels, and lab coats have angular lapels, so it's not well representative of medical linens. It's more reminiscent of a maid's uniform from the '50s. Use a modern lab coat as a reference to sharpen up the collar, while keeping the heart shape largely unchanged. Also, this mix of sans and brush script feels like inharmonious clash of old and modern. Replace the script "M" with the sans version below to pull those elements together. It will look even more cohesive with the angled lapel in place. Good luck!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep what you have, but either decrease the radii of the collar corners or even un-round 'em completely - give your edge profile more power there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to dismiss the logo that you have created, in my opinion it is very well resolved. Creating a double graphic reading is never easy and I think you have come to a very good solution, it is exaggeratedly clear what the company does.

But... I understand the client point. And the reason for my understanding is the doubt I had when I saw your logo the first time:

- Is it a medical gown? If yes, it looks a bit childish or cartoonist

[image: Gown]

- Is it the neck of a medical gown? If yes, it looks a bit feminine, I think the gowns are unisex and the medical gown doesn't have a lapel.

[image: neck]

As I pointed out before, I think you have it very well solved the concept and the graphic transformation. You must optimize it.

My proposal is to find a real image (B), compare it with the one made (A), see what are the essential elements of a gown that have been lost in your final image and recover them (C).

[image: end]